# Basic equipment needed for all grain brewing

Tags: equipment, all-grain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the minimum amount of equipment to dabble in All-Grain?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-the-minimum-amount-of-equipment-to-dabble-in-all-grain)

I'm considering working on my first all-grain brew batch. What are the bare essentials of equipment to do all-grain?

(I was surprised that I didn't find a comprehensive answer to this question here -- though I have some good how-tos on other sites. If I just missed a question already posted, just let me know!)

Answer (score 1):

This is a dupe, [What is the minimum amount of equipment to dabble in All-Grain?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-the-minimum-amount-of-equipment-to-dabble-in-all-grain), but I figure I'll throw in my 2 cents again.

The bare minimum you need is a big filter, you can mash-in-a-bag.  However, I recommend spending the few extra buck and putting together a semi decent mash tun.  Once you see how easy and fun all-grain brewing is, you probably won't look back.

[edit]: vote to close, but I figured an answer would be more helpful than just the close vote.